# How to use max id in laravel5.0 eloqeunt relationship?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'v use below function to select the last id from **schedul**  table but it not cocrrected

```
'loan'=>function($s) {
      $s->with(['schedule'=>function($schedule){
      $schedule->select(DB::raw('loan_id, schedule_date, principal as schedule_principal','max(id) as id'));
   }]);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `select` to:

```
DB::raw('loan_id, schedule_date, principal as schedule_principal, max(id) as id')
```